# How does WP custom post types fare compared to Drupal's?

Tags: custom-post-types

In Drupal you have the GUI to create whatever type you want. How about in WP, do I still have to code to create one?

Comment: Drupal is beautiful on the inside, ugly on the outside. WP is the other way around :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though there are plugins to register Custom Post Types in WordPress, this is not the way it should be done.

According to core developer Andrew Nacin, Custom Post Types should be implemented (in code) not registered (by clicks).

This makes them more managable and easier to improve and further develop or hack. Also, code versioning is the way it goes.

Comment: Can you post a link to Nacin's comments? A quick google search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: As far as I can remember it was a tweet that I cannot track down. But we can have Nacin here hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, you can use the [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin to create one with a GUI. If it doesn't have to be an actual custom post type, you could also use [PODS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/), which achieves a similar result using a custom object type.

Comment: PODS doesn't use native custom post types, but has it's own "content types".

Comment: @Ian, Not necessarily what? Custom Post Type UI uses database to register CPT which is the same way Drupal does, which is wrong. CPT UI has lately a beta feature that gives you the code to paste instead though. (According to plugin page), which is great

Comment: He asked if he had to write code to create a custom post type; that's what the "not necessarily" was in response to. You don't necessarily have to write code, you can also use a plugin to do it for you.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Something told me you were talking to me :)